# ViewPager slide with webview

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm building an android application of some kind of biography. I have to load aprox. 9 urls into different webviews. I have a Viewpager and I add a webview for each url I have. The first webview loads a local html file, the others loads facebook, instagram, youtube and other webpages. 
My problem is that the whole loading process is taking very long. Even the first page is loading slow when I have all the links added. Sometimes the pages do not render until I swipe between the webview slides. Here is my implementation:

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);

        pageMap.put(position, view);

        final WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        final RelativeLayout loadingLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.loadinLayout);
        final TextView  tvProgress = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvProgress);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                tvProgress.setText(progress+" %");
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(loadingLayout));
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl(urls[position].split("\\|",-1)[0]);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webView.reload();
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
        );

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

How could I speed up the loading process, or prioritize the webviews loading order?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setOffscreenPageLimit`

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_items);
```

where `no_of_items` is the integer to set the no of items to be preloaded on either side of your current viewpager item. Suppose you set this value to 2, then 2 items on either side of current viewpager item would be prefetched.

Comment: I used it, for the maximum fragments, but the load is still horrible

Comment: try setting a smaller value, for better result

Comment: I also added, to the onPageChangeListener, this "if (position >= currentSlidePosition) { currentSlidePosition=position;  viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(position); }"

Comment: try adding `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` and check how is the performance

Comment: now the pages remains blank until I start to swipe between them

Comment: it will be because only the two items next to current item are preloading, since you have a total of 9 items try giving 8